# Gradle setup for Kotlin multi-module project structure

Tags: kotlin, gradle, multi-module

I have a gradle project setup which looks similar to the one graphed below and I have some trouble setting up the dependencies between the different modules

```
┌Top Kotlin Project  
│  
├── Project1   
│    │
│    ├── ModuleA1 (uses C1)
│    ├── ModuleA2
│    ├── ModuleA3
│    └── settings.gradle
├── ModuleB1 (uses C1)
├── ModuleC1 (library project)
└── settings.gradle
```

The Modules in A1,A2,A3 and B1 are basically isolated Gradle applications with their own build.gradle.kts

Module C1 is supposed to be a library module with shared code, that is used by Module A1, and Module B1.

Originally I thought I only had to declare C1 as an implementation dependency in the build.gradle.kts files of A1 and B1, like this

```
implementation(project(":ModuleC1"))
```

and include it in the settings.gradle of the Top Kotlin Project and also Project 1

```
include(":ModuleC1")
project(":ModuleC1").projectDir = File("../modulec1") #this line only needed in settings.gradle of Project1
```

However this does not work for multiple reasons.

First of all, all other projects/modules need to include all the repositories ModuleC needs, which means, whenever ModuleC changes I might need to also change the build files of other modules.

Most importantly though, all modules need the kotlin gradle plugin to build.
However if ModuleC1 includes the plugin and ModuleA1 as well, I get error that
`> Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version`

If I do not include the Plugin in ModuleC1 it works for ModuleA1, but ModuleC1 cannot be built alone anymore.

The gradle.build.kts of ModuleC1 currently looks like this:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
   
    `java-library`
}

group = "org.test.project"
version = "0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1")
   
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

In conclusion I think, this setup of simply including the ModuleC1 in the other projects/modules is pretty flawed and there must be a better way to do this.

In summary, my goals are to be able to develop ModuleC1 independently but be able to use it in the other modules as if it was just another package there.

Comment: Why did you add a `settings.gradle[.kts]` in `Project1`?

Comment: Because ModuleA1, A2 and A3 are standalone applications and there are also a Project2 and Project3 (which I ommitted for brevity). The idea was to isolate the projects from one another.

Comment: I think the `settings.gradle` was originally created when `gradle init` was executed for each project

Comment: Then you might need to use `includeBuild("../ModuleC1")` instead of `include` from the ProjectN's `settings.gradle[.kts]` (assuming `ModuleC1` also has its own `settings.gradle[.kts]`

Comment: ModuleC1 does not have a settings.gradle as it is a submodule of Project1 and not a project itself. A workaround I found that at least lets me continue is to publish ModuleC1 to my localMaven repo and include it as an dependency from there.

Comment: I don't understand then. Why is `ModuleC1` a submodule of `Project1` but not nested there like the others? Why this structure? I thought `ModuleC1` was a shared module used by more projects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247178/discussion-between-fchris-and-joffrey).